# Realm: While writing a new object, how can I avoid creating an object for a relation?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

In Realm, what's the right way of creating a new object, without creating a new object for one of its relations?

Let's say I have the object `Person` with a one-to-one relation to the `Job` entity.

My code writes first 10 `Jobs` objects and then creates 10 other `Person` objects with the previously created objects.

Since the `Person` didn't exist before, the flag for `update` is false.

```
realm.add(person, update: false)
```

But since the `Job` object already existed it throws the follow exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException'.'Can't set
>   primary key property '' to existing value ''.'

Comment: The error message sounds like iOS so I'm not sure, but you should try re-using a **detached** instance of the RealmObject.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you please post an example?

Comment: That's perplexing. Are you even using primary keys in your model definition?

Comment: Can you show your class definition codes and the part you create the objects and add them to Realm?

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you are trying to define a Realm object with primary key, but you didn't modify the key value.

For example:

```
class User: Object {
  dynamic var user    = ""
  dynamic var year    = ""
  dynamic var id      = ""
  dynamic var workouts = 0

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
  }
}
```

if you don't set the `id` value, you will get the following message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException'.'Can't set primary key property ' ' to existing value ' '.'

There are several ways to solve it:

1. Don't use primary key ([not really recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322460/should-i-define-the-primary-key-for-each-entity-in-realm/32322677#comment63773704_32322677))
2. Make sure you set the `id` when creating an `Object`